# React Grid: Formatting Sections within Column

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have:

```
<Grid fluid={true}>
  <Row>
    <Col md={4}>
       <section>
          // my component
       </section>
       <section>
          // my component
       </section>
    </Col>
    <Col md={4}>
       <section>
         // my component
       </section>
       <section>
         // my component
       </section>
     </Col>
```

In this situation, I see on the browser two sets of grey dashed boxes that are touching, with a gap between each set.

[image]

What I am trying to do is get these boxes to display tightly packed, with only a small gap between them.  Then, I would like to fill them in with color.  How would I go about doing this with the react grid section?

Comment: What does "display tightly packed, with only a small gap between them." mean? You want an equal gap between each box? You are seeing the gap because you have your `section`s split into two columns. Put all 4 `section`s in the same `<Col>` to remove the gap.

Comment: If I put them into the same col, they get stacked as in a box @ChaseDeAnda (have tried everything.)

Comment: Which react-grid package are you using? Can you link it?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda react-bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you want to put each section in a column that is equally distributed in the row:

```
<Grid fluid>
    <Row>
        <Col md={3}>
            <section>
                // my component
            </section>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
            <section>
                // my component
            </section>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
            <section>
                // my component
            </section>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
            <section>
                // my component
            </section>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Grid>
```

[react-grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) uses the 12 grid system, so you want your 4 columns equally distributed across 12 sections. So 4 / 12 = 3. You'll need 4 columns that each stretch 3 sections.

Comment: Oh, right--yes this is almost it... I think I see the solution though. What I would like to do is have the columns all to the left--so maybe six columns, with two blank?

Comment: As long as it equals out to 12 you're good, so yeah blank columns should add a "padding" to the row